# Error while running spock testing with gradle in eclipse InternalTestExecutionException

Tags: gradle, groovy, spock

I am getting exception while running spock test with gradle in eclipse. In Gradle task tab "Run build" having a red icon of failure, when I right click on it to see the error it gives InternalTestExecutrionException.

> org.gradle.tooling.internal.protocol.test.InternalTestExecutionException: Error while running test(s)

My Code is very simple and below is the code is there something I am missing on gradle project build.

```
import spock.lang.*

class HelloSpockSpec extends spock.lang.Specification {

  def "length of Spock's and his friends' names"() {
    expect:
    name.size() == length

     where:
     name     | length
     "Spock"  | 3
     "Kirk"   | 4
     "Scotty" | 6
 }
}
```

Comment: Well, "Spock" has a length of 4 characters, not 3, but I guess that is not your problem?

Answer (score 0):

My above problem resolved by adding code in build.gradle file.

> apply plugin: 'groovy'